# Выдаёт ошибку когда устанавливаю pyinstaller через pip

Tags: pyinstaller

При установке pyinstaller'а, выводит эту ошибку:
C:\Python>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
Using cached PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing wheel metadata ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\света\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\света\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\32E7~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpompcjrdh'
cwd: C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-koj1235m\pyinstaller
Complete output (36 lines):
running dist_info
creating C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.egg-info
writing C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
writing requirements to C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader.waf-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader.waf3-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader_sdks'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader.vagrant'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader.lock-waf*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching 'news_template.rst'
no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
creating 'C:\Users\Света\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-in2v3vkz\PyInstaller.dist-info'
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\света\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\света\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\32E7~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpompcjrdh' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Похоже, из-за русский букв в пути установки

Comment: Попробуйте через анаконду

Comment: Мне помогла установка пакета `wheel`.